# what is the purpose of FIX message Allocation Report?

Tags: fix-protocol

What is the purpose of Allocation Report message?
I read the spec but i'm not much familiar with the terms..
Can someone give an insight?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[FIX message sent from sell-side to buy-side, sell-side to 3rd-party or 3rd-party to buy-side, the Allocation Report  (Claim) provides account breakdown of an order or set of orders plus any additional follow-up front-office information developed post-trade during the trade allocation, matching and calculation phase.](http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/FIXimate/FIXimate3.0/?language=en&version=FIX.5.0SP2)

Use the Fiximate website when in doubt.

Comment: @DumCoder <- yes, i read it but couldn't understand much from it. is it something to update the buy side when there are changes on the position?

Answer (score 1):

The Accounts or Set of Accounts used in the Order is included in the  FIX Allocation Reports. Earlier this is carried out in the Allocation Instructions which includes the Expense/Commission details incurred from the Sell Side to the Buy Side.

Now this is supported in the Allocation Report level.

Source:
http://www.onixs.biz/fix-dictionary/4.4/msgType_J_74.html